# Terminate Java Fx Application While loop in Runnable Class

Tags: java, runnable

I had this class

```
public class EXEC implements Runnable{
 private final AtomicBoolean running = new AtomicBoolean(false);

 WebDriver driver;
public EXEC(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}     
public void stop() {
    running.set(false);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String pass=SampleController.getMyVariable();
     running.set(true);
     while(running.get()){
    int i=1;
    i++;
    System.out.println(i);
 }
     Platform.exit();
}
}
```

At UI Controller Class
I assigned Run and  Quit button with method like this

```
EXEC mythread=  new EXEC(drivers);

public void run()
{mythread.run();}

public void quit()
{ mythread.stop();}
```

`mythread.run()` worked for me.However It wasn't terminated
by `mythread.stop();`. Please help me how to get it